# My App is not show in play store when search by title

Tags: android

I am trying to search my app on play store using app name but could not find my app. But when we try to search using package name its show.

Any idea regarding app showing on top position by searching title of the app.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `> 100` such questions found in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is SEO factor. You need to include some keywords in description of your app, so it will become searchable. and if you added your app recently then your app will be available after few days.

and if your app performing well then it will come on top if you search by name.

Comment: Hi Pawneshwer what type of keywords include in my app description content.

Comment: keywords my some words for example if you have photo editor app then include `editor,photo editor,best editor.free editor etc`

so when someone search for editor then your app also got listed.